# How do we get the datatype and precision of columns in Teradata using query?

Tags: sql, teradata, teradatasql

I want this as a query. I tried using a query but that is not giving me proper results.
I want to get the datatype of the corresponding columns in Teradata with column name.

I tried with `dbc.columntype` and column length but I'm getting `null/?` as a value. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Here is the query I used:

```
Select c.databasename, c.columnname,c.columnlength,c.columntype 
from dbc.columnsV c
Join dbc.tablesV t
on c databasename=t.databasename
```

Comment: DBC.ColumnsV does not contain detailed information for view columns. Use `HELP COLUMN databasename.tablename.*` on an individual view to obtain this information.

Comment: Couple of things. 1 - you need to include `c.tablename = t.tablename` in your join (maybe you just missed copying that). 2 - the nulls are for columns in views.  Add `where t.tablekind = 'T' ` to your query

Comment: @Andrew So is there any way to get the precision and datatype of multiple views?

Comment: @Fred So is there any way to get the precision and datatype of multiple views?

Comment: Not in a single statement.

Comment: You can do `HELP COLUMN table_1.*, table_2.*, table_3.*;`, but this is returning a single result set without indicating the view name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand fully what is the purpose of your join, since all the columns in your select are from c and none for t. Assuming this join is not needed.

```
SELECT c.DatabaseName, c.ColumnName, c.TableName, c.ColumnLength,c.ColumnType 
FROM DBC.ColumnsV c
WHERE c.DatabaseName = '<The Database you want to query>';
```

As mentioned in previous answers, the columns that belong to views will appear NULL in this query since views are just a way to view data on tables, so the column Length and Type is defined in the table from which the view derives.